# Creating a section containing notes

Tags: sectioning, numbering, environments

**What is needed:** A section at the end of the document, say `Notes`, and an environment, say `NewNote` with the following requirements:

1. The section `Notes` appears at the end of the document.
2. An instance of

   ```
   \begin{NewNote}
       An important note.
   \end{NewNote}
   ```

anywhere in the document appends to the section `Notes` the following:

```
Note (number): An important note.
```

where `(number)` is the note-number in the `Notes` section.

---

I have no idea how to even start with this. Any help or thoughts are appreciated.

Comment: You could use the `todonotes` [package](http://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/todonotes/todonotes.pdf) or similar notes one such as `todo` that do as you require. They're not environments though but I use `todonotes` in my documents after recently discovering it. The notes section can be placed wherever using `\listoftodos`, it includes `missing figure` templates where you can put notes of figures you want to use. Failing that, hope someone can answer

Comment: Have you looked at the `endnotes` package? If you use the `memoir` class it natively has a wider range of options for the location and appearance of endnotes.